# understanding this map behavior

Tags: perl

I am using map to extract the first element of a 2D array. Here is the small code snippet.

```
my $array = [ [1,11,111], [2,22], undef, [4] ];

my @firstList = map { (defined $_) && $_->[0] } @$array;
```

So here I am expecting the map to return an array having elements with value either undef or first element of $array's element.

but the output is not same what I am expecting.
For undef, I am getting element of type 'scalar'.

If I change the map statement with following block, then I am getting expected result.

```
my @firstList = map { $_->[0] } @$array;
```

Please help me to understand about these two map statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both return the result of the last operation performed.

For the first, when it evaluates `(defined $_) && $_->[0]` for `undef`, it sees that `defined $_` is false and stops processing the boolean expression. `$_->[0]` isn't evaluated at all in this case. `defined $_` was the last operation evaluated, and its result was `false`, which I'm guessing is represented with a `0`.

For the second, it's the actual value from the child of `@$array` which is where it's getting the `undef` value.

Comment: I was wondering why undef->[0] works (even under `strict`). Turns out it's [autovivified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification), i.e. implicitly set to `[]` **in the original array**.

Comment: @Dallaylaen: This trips up enough people that CPAN has an "autovivification" module at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification which allows you to disable it with the command `no autovivification;`

Answer (score 0):

```
map { (defined $_) && $_->[0] }
```

actually iterates through each and every element in the array, and apply some function or expression. in out case it is the following function: `defined($_) && $_->[0]`
if your cell is undef the third cell in your array evaluates to `defined(undef) && $->[0]` ( which equals `''` you can try it..), while the other evaluates to `1 && $->[0]` which equals $->[0].

BTW, thats also the reason your second statement works, for each cell of your array, you choose the first inner cell.